# why is bash executing files after extracting them from an archive?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd /var/www/html/mydir
tar cvf backup.tar file1.php file2.php ...
mysqldump -u$1 -p$2 $3 mytable > sqlbackup.sql
tar xvf mypatch.tar
mysql -u$1 -p$2 $3 < mysqlpatchfromthetarpatch.sql
echo 'Success.'
```

**Angry edit:**
I don't understand the downvote. In case that guy can't read a post from start to finish, i want to just extract some files, not run them. Here's the error:

```
[root@webserver]# ./myscript.sh user "password" dbname
file1.php
: No such file or directorycle.php: line 1: ?php
include/DatabaseObject/Article.php: line 2: class: command not found
```

file1.php is called include/Controllers/AdminController.php and the next file is called include/DatabaseObject/Article.php, i'm assuming that's why i got

```
: No such file or directorycle.php: line 1: ?php
```

After extracting my files, it breaks on an error that's inside file1.php.
What can I do?

Comment: Be more specific. What means "breaks on an error inside file1.php"?

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: Can you run the program with the +x argument in the shebang?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you have have not given us the full script, and you have anonymized the critical and detail that is causing your problem   Put a `set -x` at the top of your script.  This basically echos every command that is being run.  If you still can't figure out out with this verbose output post the exact command that `set -x` reports that was issued before the error.

Comment: As Zoredache says, please give us all the detail.  It's not helpful only to show the bits you think are relevant to the error; if you understood the error, you'd fix it yourself, so the fact you're posting here means you don't understand why it's failing, which in turn means your judgement about what's relevant may be faulty.  We like to help, but it's easier for us - and faster for you - if we have as much information as possible up front.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The error was because I had a line feed character in the tar cvf command. I couldn't spot it while editing the file with nano because the command involved a lot of files. The line feed was somehow introduced while copying the text from my text editor into my Putty console.

Answer (score 4):

Does one of your filenames have a control character in it, such as & or ; ?